# TensorFlow: Auto operator placement in distributed environment

Tags: tensorflow, distributed

I am new to Tensorflow and I get stuck these days when trying to run a model on TF in a distrubted manner. As I've gone through [Distributed TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/how_tos/distributed/index.html), I know how I can specify which operations need to be placed on which devices.

But what I want is that given a dataflow graph and a set of devices on multiple machines, TF can determine by itself how this graph should be split and where each part should be placed.

But I failed to find a proper solution to do so. So I wonder 
1. If TF can automatically split the dataflow graph and place each part to multiple machines?
2. How should I write the code? An example would be much helpful!

Answer (score 0):

TF has its own way to place different parts of the graph across different devices (not necessarily machines, as 1 GPU counts as 1 device, but 1 machine could have 8 GPUs). The mechanics behind variable/operation placement are related to cost estimation, and some heuristic metrics, which are described in [TF white paper](http://download.tensorflow.org/paper/whitepaper2015.pdf).